# stored procedures executed through jdbc

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, jdbc

I've created some stored procedures on a mysql database, but when I try to execute them I get:

```
User does not have access to metadata required to determine stored procedure parameter types. If rights can not be granted, configure connection with "noAccessToProcedureBodies=true" to have driver generate parameters that represent INOUT strings irregardless of actual parameter types.
```

I added to my connection string noAccessToProcedureBodies=true, but I still get this message. I use the DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password) method, and the url I use is

```
jdbc:mysql://[server-url]/[database-name]?noAccessToProcedureBodies=true
```

EDIT: what I meant was that I have a user, called creautenti, that I use in this method to create new users:

```
public static boolean creazioneUtente(String user, String password) throws EccezioneDaMostrare{
    if(apriConnessione(CREA_UTENTI_USER, CREA_UTENTI_PW, false)){
        try{
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            String sqlCommand="CREATE USER ? @'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD ?";
            String sqlCommandGrant="GRANT EXECUTE ON salvataggi.* TO ? REQUIRE SSL;";
            String sqlCommandGrantEx="GRANT SELECT ON `mysql`.`proc` TO ? @'%';";
            PreparedStatement s=conn.prepareStatement(sqlCommand);
            PreparedStatement sGrant=conn.prepareStatement(sqlCommandGrant);
            PreparedStatement sGrantEx=conn.prepareStatement(sqlCommandGrantEx);
            s.setString(1, user);
            sGrant.setString(1, user);
            sGrantEx.setString(1, user);
            s.setString(2, mySQLPASSWORD(password));
            s.execute();
            sGrant.executeUpdate();
            sGrantEx.executeUpdate();
            conn.commit();
            conn.setAutoCommit(true);
            chiudiConnessione();
            return true;
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            try {
                conn.rollback();
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                String msg=String.format("Errore durante la connessione al server MySQL:\n Messaggio:%s \n Stato SQL:%s \n Codice errore:%s", e.getMessage(), e.getSQLState(), e.getErrorCode());
                throw new EccezioneDaMostrare(msg);
            }
            chiudiConnessione();
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

(the first line just opens a connection with the server as creautenti, and conn is the Connection object). So I logged in as root on the server, and called

```
GRANT SELECT ON `mysql`.`proc` TO 'creautenti'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

which updated creautenti's privileges accordingly, but when I call

```
GRANT SELECT ON `mysql`.`proc` TO '<username>'@'%';
```

logged in as creautenti on any other user, the privileges aren't modified. All the routines are in salvataggi, on which I give EXECUTE privileges to every user, so I don't think that's the problem either.

Answer (score 4):

You might be better off actually granting access on the `mysql.proc` table to your application user. So connect to your MySQL database as root and run the following:

```
GRANT SELECT ON `mysql`.`proc` TO '<username>'@'%';
```

Your Java app should then be able to see the correct metadata without having to specify `noAccessToProcedureBodies=true`

Also ensure that the user under which you are connecting to the database has execute privileges on the procedure in question. Again, as root user or a user with grant privileges:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE db.storedproc TO '<username>'@'%';
```

Good luck!

Comment: okay, I tried that and it worked when granting it from the root user. The problem is, I have a user that deals with user creation and privileges granting, so I added WITH GRANT OPTION to the SQL command. Nonetheless, when I call the method that creates a new user and gives it privileges, it still can't execute stored procedures. I tried giving the privilege via MySQL Workbench too (I logged as the user I called the grant on from root, then tried calling the same grant on another one) and absolutely nothing happened. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm struggling to follow you exactly! Your original problem is solved when you run the 'grant select ...' as root right? But you don't wish to grant privileges as root. Instead you want to grant privileges using another user that you have specified 'WITH GRANT OPTION'? Also when you say 'absolutely nothing happened' - what were you expecting to happen? Could you flesh out your question with more details please?

Comment: I tried substituting the CallableStatements with PreparedStatements and now it works. Still, I don't know why it didn't, since as far as I know stored procedures should be called through that class.

Answer (score 3):

TLDR; Change your Callable Statement to reference parameters by index instead of name.

After having a similar problem I updated my JDBC driver mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar.
The error then changed from

> User does not have access to metadata required to determine stored
>   procedure parameter types. If rights can not be granted, configure
>   connection with "noAccessToProcedureBodies=true" to have driver
>   generate parameters that represent INOUT strings irregardless of
>   actual parameter types.

to

> No access to parameters by name when connection has been configured not to access procedure bodies

I changed my Callable Statement to reference parameters by index instead of name, and hey presto it works.

Updating the driver may not be necessary, just knowing to use indexes instead of names when you don't have metadata access or routine body access.

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

Following steps worked for me in mysql

Step 1 : add/edit following

Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://ipaddress:3306/logparser?noAccessToProcedureBodies = true ", "root", "");

Step 2 : Execute following query
GRANT ALL ON logparser.proc TO root@'%';

where logparser is DB name and proc is procedure name.