# how can I make this user (Normal Users) permission to use the procedure

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures, sql-grant

//This is my MySQL Code

```
START TRANSACTION;
BEGIN;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE ViewTempUserInfo (IN Log_Name VARCHAR(45),IN user_Pass VARCHAR(45), 
OUT ID_ INT, out Email VARCHAR(60), out UName VARCHAR(60))

BEGIN

SELECT Costumors_ID into ID_ FROM costumors 
where Costumors_ID= (select Costumors_ID from costumors 
where costumors.Cos_Login_Name = Log_Name and costumors.Cos_Password=user_Pass);

select Cos_Name into UName FROM costumors
where Costumors_ID= ID_;

select Cos_Email into Email FROM costumors 
where Costumors_ID= ID_;

END //
DELIMITER ;
COMMIT;

call ViewTempUserInfo('r','r',@A, @B,@C);

select @A, @B,@C;

GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE ViewTempUserInfo TO NormalUsers@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '2345NormalUsers2345';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

//This is my Java code

```
//STEP 1. Import required packages
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Procedure {
   // JDBC driver name and database URL

   static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/testarxampp?allowMultiQueries=true";


    private static String userName= "root";                     //NormalUsers
    private static String password = "DatabasteknikKursen12";   //2345NormalUsers2345
    private static String serverName = "127.0.0.1";
    private static String portNumber = "3306";
    private static String dbName = "testarxampp";

   //  Database credentials
   //static final String USER = "NormalUsers";
   //static final String PASS = "2345NormalUsers2345";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Connection conn = null;
   CallableStatement stmt = null;
   try{
      //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

      //STEP 3: Open a connection
      System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
      Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
      connectionProps.put("user", userName);
      connectionProps.put("password", password );
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + serverName + ":" + portNumber + "/" + dbName, connectionProps);

      //STEP 4: Execute a query
        String userNamex = "abli";
        String Passwordx = "ablinana";
      System.out.println("Creating statement...");
      String sql = "{call ViewTempUserInfo(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}";
      stmt = conn.prepareCall(sql);

      //Bind IN parameter first, then bind OUT parameter

      stmt.setString(1, userNamex); // This would set ID as 102
      // Because second parameter is OUT so register it
      stmt.setString(2, Passwordx);

      stmt.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
      stmt.registerOutParameter(4, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
      stmt.registerOutParameter(5, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);

      //Use execute method to run stored procedure.
      System.out.println("Executing stored procedure..." );
      stmt.execute();

      //Retrieve employee name with getXXX method

      System.out.println("Emp Name with ID:" + 
              userNamex + " is " + Passwordx);



      System.out.println("ID    : " + stmt.getInt(3));
      System.out.println("Email    : " + stmt.getString(4));
      System.out.println("name    : " + stmt.getString(5));

      stmt.close();
      conn.close();
   }catch(SQLException se){
      //Handle errors for JDBC
      se.printStackTrace();
   }catch(Exception e){
      //Handle errors for Class.forName
      e.printStackTrace();
   }finally{
      //finally block used to close resources
      try{
         if(stmt!=null)
            stmt.close();
      }catch(SQLException se2){
      }// nothing we can do
      try{
         if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
         se.printStackTrace();
      }//end finally try
   }//end try
    System.out.println("Goodbye!");
```

everything works fine and I get the following

```
Connecting to database...
Creating statement...
Executing stored procedure...
Emp Name with ID:abli is ablinana
ID    : 6
Email    : asdf@asdf.se
name    : asdf
Goodbye!
```

but if I change these lines

```
private static String userName= "root";                     //NormalUsers
private static String password = "DatabasteknikKursen12";   //2345NormalUsers2345
```

to this

```
private static String userName= "NormalUsers";                      //NormalUsers
private static String password = "2345NormalUsers2345"; //2345NormalUsers2345
```

I get the following error.

```
Connecting to database...
Creating statement...
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter number 3 is not an OUT parameter
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:996)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:935)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:924)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:870)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.CallableStatement.checkIsOutputParam(CallableStatement.java:659)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.CallableStatement.registerOutParameter(CallableStatement.java:1860)
    at Procedure.main(Procedure.java:48)
Goodbye!
```

someone who understands what I've been doing wrong somewhere or how to get around the problem without giving NormalUsers all privileger as the root user. I use the mysql-connector-java-1.5.34-bin and tested to switch to mysql-connector-java-5.1.4 but that has not helped. have similar problems in many of my classes in java. it should be sufficient with:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE ViewTempUserInfo TO NormalUsers@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '2345NormalUsers2345';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

????????????????please, please, please explain???????????????

in a similar thread, someone has given an answer I do not understand. 've tried everything now except this

[stored procedures executed through jdbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876397/stored-procedures-executed-through-jdbc)?

```
TLDR; Change your Callable Statement to reference parameters by index instead of name.

After having a similar problem I updated my JDBC driver mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar. The error then changed from

    User does not have access to metadata required to determine stored procedure parameter types. If rights can not be granted, configure connection with "noAccessToProcedureBodies=true" to have driver generate parameters that represent INOUT strings irregardless of actual parameter types.

to

    No access to parameters by name when connection has been configured not to access procedure bodies

I changed my Callable Statement to reference parameters by index instead of name, and hey presto it works.

Updating the driver may not be necessary, just knowing to use indexes instead of names when you don't have metadata access or routine body access.

Good Luck
share|edit

answered Aug 2 '13 at 13:26
Kickaha
603319
```

someone who knows what he means by Changed CallableStatement to reference parameters by index instead of name
what should be changed, can someone please explain.

Comment: Have you tried logging in to the database as "NormalUsers" and dropping the ViewTempUserInfo procedure? You could have an old version of the proc deployed under that user.

Comment: no, have not done it, but I've logged in as root and created the ViewTemplateUserInfo and given NormalUser privileges several times. Normal User may not have privileges to create, delete Procedures, only EXECUTE. do you think I should give NormalUser privileges to DROP, CREAT Procedures.

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying the database name:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE testarxampp.ViewTempUserInfo TO 'NormalUsers'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '2345NormalUsers2345';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: I tried this but got the following error now.                  `Connecting to database...
Creating statement...
java.sql.SQLException: User does not have access to metadata required to determine stored procedure parameter types. If rights can not be granted, configure connection with "noAccessToProcedureBodies=true" to have driver generate parameters that represent INOUT strings irregardless of actual parameter types.


Goodbye!`       can not fit the whole error in this box

Comment: This is a problem with the java connector. Try connecting directly via command line or MySql Workbench.

Comment: it works fine from the command line or MySQL Workbench. it is from java i have the the problem. I`m creating a Java application

Comment: Once you add the grant in mysql it should be stored in MySql so when you connect from java the permission should be there. Try adding it from command line and then test running your procedure from java.

Comment: I think it is an error when the driver fetches the procedure metadata from the database.  When I step through in the debugger, it shows the correct number of parameters, but all have the form `IN x VARCHAR`.  The `noAccessToProcedureBodies` is a variable in the source code that tells the driver to just trust the application.