# SimpleJdbcCall with no access to procedure bodies errors failing due to incorrect number of arguments

Tags: java, mysql, spring, stored-procedures, spring-jdbc

I have a SimpleJdbcCall object that I created with a dbcp2.BasicDataSource like so:

```
proc_searchDb = 
   new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource())
          .withProcedureName(proc1)
          .returningResultSet(getResultSetFlag(),new DbManagerDataMapper());
proc_searchDb.compile();
```

In the data source I am using, I set the `noAccessToProcedureBodies=true` since my user does not have access to the stored procedure's body and fails to retrieve metadata.

The problem I have now is that when I call `execute` on `proc_searchDb` with a map of input parameters, it fails and logs this error:

```
jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE my_db.searchDbByKey; expected 3, got 0
```

This is how I am calling it:

```
Map<String, Object> inputMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
inputMap.put("in_param1",0);
inputMap.put("in_param2",1);
inputMap.put("in_param3",2);
Map<String, Object> results = proc_getDbManager.execute(inputMap);
```

[I read elsewhere that a possible solution to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876397/stored-procedures-executed-through-jdbc) is to "reference parameters by index instead of name", but how would I do this with SimpleJdbcCall?

Any insight or help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How are you sending the input parameters to the StoredProc here?

Comment: @user2004685 passed into the execute method. it is just a map of k,v pairs. key being in_paramName

Comment: Could you please include that code here?

Comment: @user2004685 sure thing. added.

Comment: It looks correct to me. I hope the input parameter names i.e. `in_param1`, `in_param2` and `in_param3` are correct. You can also try using `SqlParameterSource` as follows: `SqlParameterSource inputMap = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("in_param1", 0).addValue("in_param2", 1).addValue("in_param3", 2);`

Comment: @user2004685 do the "in_param" names have to match the names exactly specified in the sproc? Or do the names not matter and just the order does?

Comment: It should match with the names of your Stored Procedure.